# 'Segmentation fault' when executing Enumerator#next in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am getting error when executing the following code in rails console:

```
[1,2,3].to_enum.next
```

Trace:

```
 (irb):1: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [i686-linux]

-- control frame ----------
c:0029 p:---- s:0103 b:0103 l:0003a0 d:0003a0 CFUNC  :next
c:0028 p:0016 s:0100 b:0100 l:001944 d:000099 EVAL   (irb):1
c:0027 p:---- s:0098 b:0098 l:000097 d:000097 FINISH
c:0026 p:---- s:0096 b:0096 l:000095 d:000095 CFUNC  :eval
c:0025 p:0028 s:0089 b:0089 l:000088 d:000088 METHOD /home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
c:0024 p:0033 s:0082 b:0081 l:000080 d:000080 METHOD /home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/context.rb:254
c:0023 p:0031 s:0076 b:0076 l:001c94 d:000075 BLOCK  /home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:159
c:0022 p:0042 s:0068 b:0068 l:000067 d:000067 METHOD /home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273
c:0021 p:0011 s:0063 b:0063 l:001c94 d:000062 BLOCK  /home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156
c:0020 p:0144 s:0059 b:0059 l:000042 d:000058 BLOCK  /home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243
c:0019 p:---- s:0056 b:0056 l:000055 d:000055 FINISH
c:0018 p:---- s:0054 b:0054 l:000053 d:000053 CFUNC  :loop
c:0017 p:0009 s:0051 b:0051 l:000042 d:000050 BLOCK  /home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229
c:0016 p:---- s:0049 b:0049 l:000048 d:000048 FINISH
c:0015 p:---- s:0047 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 CFUNC  :catch
c:0014 p:0023 s:0043 b:0043 l:000042 d:000042 METHOD /home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228
c:0013 p:0046 s:0040 b:0040 l:001c94 d:001c94 METHOD /home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155
c:0012 p:0011 s:0037 b:0037 l:00155c d:000036 BLOCK  /home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70
c:0011 p:---- s:0035 b:0035 l:000034 d:000034 FINISH
c:0010 p:---- s:0033 b:0033 l:000032 d:000032 CFUNC  :catch
c:0009 p:0183 s:0029 b:0029 l:00155c d:00155c METHOD /home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69
c:0008 p:0210 s:0024 b:0024 l:001828 d:001828 METHOD /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@ekobilet/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44
c:0007 p:0019 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@ekobilet/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8
c:0006 p:0430 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 TOP    /home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@ekobilet/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:0013d4 d:001aa4 EVAL   script/rails:6
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0013d4 d:0013d4 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
/home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@ekobilet/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@ekobilet/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
/home/pablo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@ekobilet/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156:in `block in eval_input'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/context.rb:254:in `evaluate'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80:in `evaluate'
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80:in `eval'
(irb):1:in `irb_binding'
(irb):1:in `next'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_vm_bugreport+0x78) [0xb76d28e8]
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x55e43) [0xb759ce43]
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_bug+0x33) [0xb759dc53]
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x115d73) [0xb765cd73]
[0xb777940c]
/home/pablo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x221000) [0xb7768000]

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

I am working on ubuntu 12.10 with ruby 1.9.2:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [i686-linux]
```

Bug is also happening with ruby 1.9.2-p290 but with 1.9.3 it works ok. Unfortunatelly i am not able to upgrade ruby version since I am working with legacy rails app:

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'unicorn', '4.0.1'
gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'
gem 'mongrel', '1.2.0.pre2'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.18', :require => 'mysql2'
gem 'attribute_normalizer', '~> 0.3.1'
gem 'cubus-settingslogic', '~> 2.2.0', :require => 'settingslogic'
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
gem 'sinatra', '1.1.3'
gem 'tilt', '1.2.2'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.6.1'
gem 'resque', '~> 1.17.0', :require => "resque/server"
gem 'faraday', '0.5.7'
gem 'httparty', '0.7.8'
gem 'resque_mailer', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'omniauth', '0.2.0'
gem 'pdfkit', '~> 0.5.2'
gem 'exception_notification', :require => 'exception_notifier'
gem 'whenever', '~> 0.6.2', :require => false
gem 'meta_search'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 3.2'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.5.1'
gem 'carrierwave_backgrounder', '0.0.6'
gem 'fgraph', '0.6.0'
gem 'hirb'
gem 'resque-retry'
gem 'event-calendar', '~> 2.3.3', :require => 'event_calendar'
gem 'activerecord-import', '~> 0.2.11'
gem 'oink'
gem "truncate_html", "~> 0.9.1"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6.1'
  gem 'active_reload'
  gem "parallel_tests"
  gem 'fuubar'
  gem 'awesome_print'
end

group :production do
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end

group :development do
  gem 'lol_dba'
  gem 'request-log-analyzer'
  gem 'query_reviewer'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'better_errors'
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov', '>= 0.4.0', :require => false
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 1.4.0'
  gem "factory_girl", "~> 2.3.0"
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.21.1'
  gem 'capybara', '1.0.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 0.4.0'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :git => 'git://github.com/ttilley/rb-fsevent.git', :branch => 'pre-compiled-gem-one-off'
  gem 'escape_utils', '~> 0.2.3'
  gem 'launchy', '~> 2.0.5'
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 0.9.0"
  gem 'timecop', '~> 0.3.5'
  gem 'resque_spec'
  gem 'vcr', '~> 1.11.3'
  gem 'webmock', '~> 1.7.8'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 1.2.0'
  gem 'rr'
 end
```

I have tried reinstalling ruby version couple of times and it does not help.

Any help would be great appreciated!

Comment: So what? Well, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an issue for this reported against Ubuntu, but [I do see one for OS X Lion](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5003). You might consider figuring out where exactly to report the issue against 1.9.2 and try to see if anyone in the community there can give you more guidance on how to get a bug report (a) verified as an actual bug and not caused by something else, and (b) where and how to file the bug if it does get verified.

I don't believe you're supposed to create issues directly in the backport page, but at least for reference here are the list of issues on the 1.9.2 backport list.

- https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-192/issues?set_filter=1

Comment: thank you for the answer. after several ruby reinstalls using both rvm rbenv and ubuntu version 13.04 i gave up my hope to fix this bug on my machine.